# How to create a queue that will re-render a component after a certain amount of time?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, react-state-management

I'm creating a game. There's a header, and whenever someone answers the question correctly, **the title will be replaced by that person's name** for **2 minutes**, and then be replaced back by the title, however, if there are 2 or more people answering the question at the same time. The interval between them will be 10 seconds, and then it will return back to the header after 2 minutes if no one else answers anything correctly.

My approach is to create an array, set a timeout so it will pop the item out, and set the header state, however, the first person who answers the question will be delayed by 10 seconds too.

EDIT: Here's my approach. However, the name is usually switched faster than expected

```js
const [header, setHeader] = useState(headerLogo)
const [name, setName] = useState({
    counter: -1,
    nameArray: [],
})
// I saved the name state in local Storage so data wont be lost after refresh
    
useEffect(() => {
    if (!webSocket.current) return
    webSocket.current.onmessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data.startsWith('{')) {
        const rawData = event.data.replaceAll(`'`, `"`)
        const data = JSON.parse(rawData)

        setName((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            nameArray: [
                ...prevState.nameArray,
                { name: data.name, score: data.score},
            ],
            counter: prevState.counter + 1}))
}, [name])

useEffect(() => {
    const counter = name.counter
    let a, c

    if (nameFirstBlood.nameArray.length) {
      if (counter === 0) {
        setHeader(
          <Header
            name={name.nameArray[counter].name}
            score={nameFirstBlood.nameArray[counter].name}
          />
       )
      a = setTimeout(() => {
        setHeader(headerLogo)
        setName({counter: -1,nameArray: [],})
    }, 120000)
    } 
      else if (counter >= 1) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setHeader(
                <Header
                    name={name.nameArray[counter].name}
                    flagName={name.nameArray[counter].score}
                />
            )
        }, 10000)

        a = setTimeout(() => {
                setHeader(headerLogo)
                setNameFirstBlood({counter: -1,nameArray: [],})
        }, TIME_ACTION)
    }
}
return () => {
    clearTimeout(a)
}
}, [name])

// I saved the name state in local Storage so data wont be lost after refresh
```